# Detecting system sound on Windows using Python

Tags: java, python, windows, audio, detect

Is there any way to detect system sound instead of microphone sound? I want to be able to detect whenever my system makes a sound instead of when the microphone picks up the actual sound.

One way I found to do this use an "audio loop-back in either software or hardware (e.g. connect a lead from the speaker 'out' jack to the microphone 'in' jack)."

[Capturing speaker output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644368/capturing-speaker-output-in-java)

I am building a program that plays an mp3 file whenever a system sound happens but I don't want it to go off if the dog barks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something with pyaudio (http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)

Like this:

```
import pyaudio

chunk = 1024

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=44100,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk)

data = stream.read(chunk)
```

And then you could calculate the root-mean-square(RMS) of the audio sample and go from there.

**Edited:**
You can see what kind of devices you can use by doing something like the following. (http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio.get_device_info_by_index)

```
import pyaudio    
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in xrange(0,10):
    try:
        p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    except Exception,e:print e
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it

```
import time
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities

def is_audio_playing():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        if session.State == 1:  # State == 1 means the audio session is active
            return True
    return False

while True:
    if is_audio_playing():
        print("Audio is currently playing.")
    else:
        print("No audio is playing.")
    time.sleep(1)
```